# DB2 update - remove all characters after white space

Tags: sql, db2, whitespace, removing-whitespace

```
Select Substr(<<COLUMN NAME>>, 1,(PosStr(<<COLUMNNAME>>, ' ') -1)) 
From <<TABLE NAME>>;
```

This statement here helps remove the white space, and all characters after it - which is good, this is what i'm looking for... But it is a select statment, and only returns a list.

Can someone please change this to a UPDATE statement please?
(DB2)

---

More Info... if I have for example,

```
NAME

teddy longmore

theadore rosavelt

some body
```

and I want to remove all of the characters AFTER THE FIRST WHITESPACE

How can I do that using SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty much already there, just add the command you already have to an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE your_table
   SET name = SUBSTR(name, 1,(POSSTR(name, ' ') -1));
```

Demonstration:

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEXT_TEST (
    NAME VARCHAR(50)
) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO SESSION.TEXT_TEST (
    SELECT 'teddy longmore' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'theadore rosavelt' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'some body' FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
);

SELECT name
FROM SESSION.TEXT_TEST;

UPDATE SESSION.TEXT_TEST
   SET NAME = SUBSTR(name, 1,(POSSTR(name, ' ') -1));

SELECT name
FROM SESSION.TEXT_TEST;
```

Comment: Why would you INSERT with SELECT UNION SELECT UNION SELECT, when VALUES would work so much simpler (and more efficient too)

Comment: @WarrenT: hah, been using Mainframe DB2 lately, where a insert from values clause isn't available... That would be great on LUW (I don't use iSeries, so I can't talk about that)

Comment: Looks like you've got [INSERT by VALUE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_sql_insert.htm) for a single row, at least in v10.  I'm not sure how far back it goes.  On i, we can use VALUES (row),(row),...  I think the same is true for LUW.  We often feel like the forgotten child on i, but turns out we have some even cooler things you guys don't. So I guess it's a little more even than it sometimes feels.  ;-)

Comment: Yep, you can only do a single row in a `VALUE` clause. There are multi-row inserts, but that only works in an application program, using host arrays. One of the big things I miss on DB2 z/OS. :(

Answer (score 0):

The syntax would be

```
UPDATE mytable
    SET col = expression
    WHERE conditional-expression
```